# In tf.nn.dropout what is the effect of keep_prob argument?

Tags: tensorflow

I am learning tf.nn.dropout command. Documentation says that with probability keep_prob, outputs the input element scaled up by 1 / keep_prob, otherwise outputs 0. The scaling is so that the expected sum is unchanged. Can someone please explain that why we take 1/keep_prob. And if I set its value 0.1. Does it mean that I am keeping only 10 percent nodes?

Answer (score 1):

The scaling factor is set to `1/keep_prob` because the dropout is should be disabled at testing or evaluation. See the high level API on layers of tensorflow: [tf.layers.dropout](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dropout).

During testing or evaluation, the activation of each unit is unscaled. The scaling factor of 1/keep_prob during training makes sure that the expected activation (keep_prob * (1/keep_prob) = 1) is the same as that in testing.
More information can be found in this [paper](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~rsalakhu/papers/srivastava14a.pdf).

Suppose you have 10 units in the layer and set the keep_prob to 0.1, Then the activation of 9 randomly chosen units out of 10 will be set to 0, and the remaining one will be scaled by a factor of 10. I think a more precise description is that you only keep the activation of 10 percent of the nodes.